# Multi role user login and session

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with multi role user login in PHP MySQL, I tried the code without error handling to see if it works but it doesn't; any tip would be much appreciated thank you

```
session_start();

if( isset($_POST['submit'])){   

    include 'db.php';

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM utilisateur WHERE username = '$username'";    
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $SESSION['Id'] = $row['Id'];    
        $SESSION['login'] = $row['login'];
        $SESSION['type'] = $row['type'];
        if( $SESSION['type'] == "admin" ){
        header('Location: admin.html');}
        else if( $SESSION['type'] == "Cardio" ){
        header('Location: Cardio.html');}
    }
}
```

Comment: ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: even after removing escape passwords it still doesnt redirect to the admin page

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What **exactly** is not working?

Comment: `$SESSION['type']` should be `$_SESSION['type']` - note the underscore. You need to change this for all of your session variables. Closing the question as a typo.

Comment: $_SESSION['type'] didn't fix the problem as for debugging i tried to echo the password acquired through form and it doesn't work

Comment: Can you share your HTML code that has the form?

Comment: It is a simple form with login password and submit button i merged html and php files and it worked as when they were separated form values didn't reach the php for a reason i don't know
thanks all for your help